# Can't call a function in another file (nodejs + express)

Tags: node.js, function, express, socket.io

I've got a simple express app and I'd like to have my socket listening info in separate files in a `sockets` directory (each file in there would correspond to a controller - separation of concerns).

In `app.js`, I'm trying to get this to work:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('game-save-comment', require('./sockets/games.js')(data));
});
```

And `./sockets/games.js` looks like:

```
var GameSockets = function(data) {
  console.log('got here');
}

exports.GameSockets = GameSockets;
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
  socket.on('game-save-comment', require('./sockets/games.js')(data));
                                                               ^
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. Since you export `GameSockets` as named function, so in `app.js` you should use it as:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('game-save-comment', require('./sockets/games.js').GameSockets(data));
});
```

However the error you are getting is not caused by this. You should pass a function to `.on()` event handler, but you try to pass there the result of  execution of this funtion. So finally your `app.js` should look like (please note absence of function call):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('game-save-comment', require('./sockets/games.js').GameSockets);
});
```